# Get custom Picklist value in LWC without Record Type

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, record-type, pricebookentry

I have created a custom Picklist in PricebookEntry and trying to get the Picklist values in LWC.
All the solutions I found needs to pass the RecordTypeId to get the list.

```
@wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, { objectApiName: PRICEBOOK_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId'})
 pickListValues;
```

For PricebookEntry, I can't create a Record Type. How can I get the Picklist values without the RecordTypeId?

Answer (score 10):

Use the "null" record type Id, "012000000000000AAA" as the record type Id.

```
@wire(getPicklistValues, { objectApiName: PRICEBOOK_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA'})
```

This is demonstrated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values).

Comment: I love how they make absolutely no mention that this ID is a "null" record type in the linked documentation.

Comment: @JohnAu Indeed. 000000000000000AAA can also be used in most cases where a null Id is expected. 012 is the key prefix for Record Type, which is why it is the null Record Type Id, but you can also use, for example, 001000000000000AAA as a null Account Id.

Comment: This is mind-blowing (and helpful). I would have had to write a bunch of js to decode picklist dependency from the validFor value without this info. Is there any documentation that talks about the existence of 'null' ids ?

Comment: @NagenSahu Null Id appears in the documentation in some rare cases, but I don't think there's a specific document that calls out null Id or its use. For example, [Filter Users by Role ID to find users without an assigned role](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387219&type=1) states how you can filter for users without a role. It's kind of hard to find much documentation on it.

Comment: I have been developing on the SF platform for almost 7 years and this is the first I have ever heard of this lol